# JavaScript Prank / Joke

Tags: javascript

How do you prank a coworker or friend in a way that's hard to notice and fix? Preferably in JavaScript, and without having install any programs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about boring pranks replacing a stupid character that any decent editor would detect immediately.

Comment: @adeneo Actually, Sublime (a very popular code editor) will not detect this at all. As long as the code editor doesn't have a plugin like JShint, it should go undetected.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

## Greek Question Mark - Semicolon Prank

*(Tested in JavaScript)*

Replace one or several semicolons in a coworker or friend's code with the Greek question mark:

`;`

(source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#Greek_question_mark)

If you compare the two, they look exactly the same: `;;`

> The first `;` is a greek question mark, and the second `;` is a normal semicolon.

The Greek question mark throws a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in JavaScript, and probably throws errors in other languages as well. Make sure you're saving the code file in Unicode/UTF-8.

Comment: ...That is evil.

Comment: Very easy to detect & fix. Usually if I don't know why I have an error at a certain line, I wipe the whole line and rewrite it.

Comment: In visual studio it compiles properly

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Interesting. It must be converting from Unicode to an encoding that doesn't have the Greek Question Mark. That means it would turn the character into a semicolon before it compiles.

Comment: Find and replace all can easily fix this though.

Comment: @BrightIntelDusk An easy fix is the perfect type of fix for a prank though. I had a coworker replace `True = False` in a python django app. Code ran fine for the most part but it cost the guy a day of work

Comment: this is not working. I typed greek question mark using alt+59

Comment: Do this in a minimised js file, and watch his world burn.

Comment: If using yarn and babel: modify the version of babel in the global yarn cache so that it writes the Greek question mark instead of semicolon.

Comment: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 47 = U037E colon U037E colon'`

Comment: @BrightIntelDusk Sure, if they happened to read this exact answer.  Otherwise, how would they know?