# Why does 2+ 40 equal 42?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I was baffled when a colleague showed me this line of JavaScript alerting 42.

```js
alert(2+ 40);
```

It quickly turns out that what looks like a minus sign is actually an arcane Unicode character with clearly different semantics.

This left me wondering why that character doesn't produce a syntax error when the expression is parsed. I'd also like to know if there are more characters behaving like this.

Comment: Did you try to run this from the console? I get -38 as result. Not sure why.

Comment: Maybe you two are running different browsers, might be browser dependent.

Comment: It's the minus sign I just found out.

Comment: @Elyasin Did you copy/paste or retype?

Comment: I copy and pasted yours. When I typed with my keyboard it was ok.

Comment: This works in Visual C# as well. When pasting the strange character into the Visual Studio IDE, or when completing the statement by typing `;`, the editor tends to change the strange ` ` character into a normal space, but if you undo that "auto-correction", you have the same behavior. That character has the same semantics as a space, even if it looks like a hyphen or minus (in usual fonts).

Comment: The opposite can happen as well. Some languages supporting unicode in identifiers accept unicode characters that look like white space (in other words, you can't see them); it may even be possible to have completely invisible identifiers.

Comment: What I want to know is how these get into code in the first place...

Comment: (OT) Because 42 is an answer to _everything?_

Comment: On Opera I see a + sign and a funny less than icon in a square. Still wondering how it can be parsed...

Comment: Re: getting them into code - should be expanded to 7-bit printables. as well as displaying properly on monitors, they will print. I am not find of programmers using hex editors on source.

Comment: I see no minus sign, just a box with the hex code.

Comment: minus1 for a non-real question: How did you know to tag this as Unicode at the time of asking question?

Comment: @Thomas the fact that the unexpected result was caused by that Unicode character was already clear.

Comment: Kudos for getting the answer to the universe. Make sure you bring your towel to work tomorrow.

Comment: There is also more advanced unicode trolling like russian chars (АВЕМНОРСТХаеорсух) and finally, capital "з" - "З": `var З=100;alert(З+2)`. Glyphs are acceptable identifiers too (javascript, php).

Comment: I feel blessed seeing the character as a box with numbers.

Answer (score 472, accepted):

That character is ["OGHAM SPACE MARK"](https://codepoints.net/U+1680), which is a space character. So the code is equivalent to `alert(2+ 40)`.

> I'd also like to know if there are more characters behaving like this.

Any Unicode character in the Zs class [is a white space character in JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-white-space), [but there don't seem to be that many](https://codepoints.net/search?q=&na=&int=&gc[]=Zs&Bidi_M=&Bidi_C=&CE=&Comp_Ex=&XO_NFC=&XO_NFD=&XO_NFKC=&XO_NFKD=&Join_C=&Upper=&Lower=&OUpper=&OLower=&CI=&Cased=&CWCF=&CWCM=&CWL=&CWKCF=&CWT=&CWU=&IDS=&OIDS=&XIDS=&IDC=&OIDC=&XIDC=&Pat_Syn=&Pat_WS=&Dash=&Hyphen=&QMark=&Term=&STerm=&Dia=&Ext=&SD=&Alpha=&OAlpha=&Math=&OMath=&Hex=&AHex=&DI=&ODI=&LOE=&WSpace=&Gr_Base=&Gr_Ext=&OGr_Ext=&Gr_Link=&Ideo=&UIdeo=&IDSB=&IDST=&Radical=&Dep=&VS=&NChar=).

However, [JavaScript also allows Unicode characters in identifiers](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6), which lets you use interesting variable names like `ಠ_ಠ`.

Comment: Box-with-a-hex-code underscore box-with-a-hex-code. Which character is it meant to be?

Comment: @immibis The last part of this answer is an emoticon available in image form at http://www.disapprovallook.com/

Comment: I'll remember that next time I need to store len(e) in a variable.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Use Python 3. AFAIK there as well you can use most Unicode characters in a variable name.

Comment: You can use Unicode letters in Java identifiers as well.

Comment: Fun little tidbit: When this comes up in a Google search, you just see the space, no symbol.

Comment: Note that not just `Zs` characters are considered to be white space in JavaScript. There are more: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regexpu/blob/ff17a00b63a017a69fd93da455a8944eb18918ce/scripts/character-class-escape-sets.js#L69-L87

Comment: Given this, the zero width no-break space, and the other space-alikes, I suspect a clever coder could hide some quite nasty things in innocuous looking SVN commits to CMS source.

Comment: `ಠ_ಠ`, more like Hoo-dini

Comment: My reaction when `ಠ_ಠ` can be used as an identifier in JS: **ಠ_ಠ**

Comment: @ChrisCirefice underscore being treated as a letter is long-standing in C-style langauges. `ಠ` being treated as a letter is just common sense, since it's a letter. It would be a clear bug if `ಠ_ಠ` couldn't be used as an identifier.

Comment: @JonHanna You're right about that - I took a compilers course for C, so I know how identifiers work ;) it's just interesting to see crazy unicode symbols instead of the typical `_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]` range (at least that's what we implemented in our compiler). The only problem with using unicode like that is that anyone opening your files with ASCII encoding (and many others) is going to have a bad time trying to figure out what the hell you coded :P

Comment: @ChrisCirefice `ಠ` isn't a "crazy unicode symbol" it's a letter from the Kannada alphabet. If someone uses Kannada in their identifiers it's not going to be very readable to me, but it might be a lot more readable to them than my code is using identifiers in crazy unicode symbols like `width`, `index`, `hashCode` etc.

Comment: @JonHanna You know I [had looked up that symbol](http://unicodelookup.com/#ಠ/1), but I didn't really read too much into *kannada letter*. Well, still, unicode poses its problems in many editors :)

Comment: RE `ಠ_ಠ`: that's *one* way to become the world's least loved JavaScript programmer

Answer (score 82):

After reading the other answers, I wrote a simple script to find all Unicode characters in the range U+0000–U+FFFF that behave like white spaces. As it seems, there are 26 or 27 of them depending on the browser, with disagreements about U+0085 and U+FFFE.

Note that most of these characters just look like a regular white space.

```js
function isSpace(ch)
{
    try
    {
        return Function('return 2 +' + ch + ' 2')() === 4;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 0xffff; ++i)
{
    var ch = String.fromCharCode(i);
    if (isSpace(ch))
    {
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('DIV')).textContent = 'U+' + ('000' + i.toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-4) + '    "' + ch + '"';
    }
}
```

```css
div { font-family: monospace; }
```

Comment: U+0085 "NEL" is defined as whitespace by Unicode but has a long history of being mishandled. U+FFFE is a noncharacter with no name and no properties besides NChar and shouldn't be be considered whitespace by anything reasonable. That said, my browser disagrees with me on both points :)

Comment: @hobbs U+FFFE is also a `\p{Default Ignorable Code Point}`, not just a `\p{Noncharacter Code Pount}`.  U+0085 has always been a `\p{Whitespace}` code point. The evil one is U+180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR, which “recently” lost its `\p{Whitespace}` property.  Note that `\p{Pattern Whitespace}` is a much smaller set, and an immutable property. But `\p{Whitespace}` is not.

Comment: `FEFF` is the BOM and can be treated like a "zero width no-break space" within texts. `FFFE` is it's endian swapped equivalent. Perhaps that's the reason some browsers treat is as whitespace.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-white-space (as linked from Felix King's answer) specifically calls out U+FEFF to be considered whitespace in JS source code.  U+FFFE is not listed, but that strikes me as an error of omission.

Comment: @zwol, it's not an error of omission, because there is no character U+FFFE. Treating it as whitespace is a bug. Indeed, treating it as a valid character at all is a bug in most cases. U+0085 is not white space according to the JS spect, but that spec's requiring special-casing of U+0085 to not be a new line is bizarre and arguably a bug in the spec.

Comment: @JonHanna You are formally correct on both counts, but I am certain that the requirement _not_ to treat U+0085 as a newline arises from bitter experience of the crap out there on the Web, and I am surprised that there is not a requirement to treat U+FFFE as if it were U+FFEF for the same reason.

Comment: If you're getting U+FFFE where you should have U+FFEF, then things are likely too messed up for anything to work anyway. If you're getting U+FFFE where you should have U+FEFF and it's not at the very start of the document, things are almost certainly too screwed up, but it's more likely to be the parser's fault than the producer.

Answer (score 58):

It appears that the character that you are using is actually longer than what the actual minus sign (a hyphen) is.

```
 
-
```

The top is what you are using, the bottom is what the minus sign should be. You do seem to know that already, so now let's see why Javascript does this.

The character that you use is actually the [ogham space mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1680/index.htm) which is a whitespace character, so it is basically interpreted as the same thing as a space, which means that your statement looks like `alert(2+ 40)` to Javascript.

There are other characters like this in Javascript. You can see a full list [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode).

---

Something interesting I noticed about this character is the way that Google Chrome (and possible other browsers) interprets it in the top bar of the page.

[image]

It is a block with `1680` inside of it. That is actually the unicode number for the ogham space mark. It appears to be just my machine doing this, but it is a strange thing.

---

I decided to try this out in other languages to see what happens and these are the results that I got.

---

#### Languages it doesn't work in:

**Python 2 & 3**

```
>> 2+ 40
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    2+ 40
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

**Ruby**

```
>> 2+ 40
NameError: undefined local variable or method ` 40' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /home/michaelpri/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

**Java** (inside the `main` method)

```
>> System.out.println(2+ 40);
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: \5760
            System.out.println(2+?40);
                                 ^
Main.java:3: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println(2+?40);
                                  ^
Main.java:3: error: illegal start of expression
            System.out.println(2+?40);
                                    ^
3 errors
```

**PHP**

```
>> 2+ 40;
Use of undefined constant  40 - assumed ' 40' :1
```

**C**

```
>> 2+ 40
main.c:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
 2+ 40
 ^
main.c:1:1: error: stray '\341' in program
main.c:1:1: error: stray '\232' in program
main.c:1:1: error: stray '\200' in program

exit status 1
```

**Go**

```
>> 2+ 40
can't load package: package .: 
main.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'INT' 2
main.go:1:3: illegal character U+1680

exit status 1
```

**Perl 5**

```
>> perl -e'2+ 40'                                                                                                                                   
Unrecognized character \xE1; marked by <-- HERE after 2+<-- HERE near column 3 at -e line 1.
```

---

#### Languages it does work in:

**Scheme**

```
>> (+ 2  40)
=> 42
```

**C#**
(inside the `Main()` method)

```
Console.WriteLine(2+ 40);

Output: 42
```

**Perl 6**

```
>> ./perl6 -e'say 2+ 40' 
42
```

Comment: Ubuntu isn't the problem. The window title font you're using is.

Comment: firefox (iceweasel) and google chrome on debian seem to display the unicode char just fine, although I have gone to lengths to ensure unicode compatibility on my system. (actually, the most useful thing I did was the simplest: `sudo apt-get install unicode`, although only after hours of research and failed attempts)

Comment: @PSkocik Interesting, I have had font problems on here before, so that is probably likely

Comment: @PSk while I don't have experience with ubuntu directly, debian definitely doesn't come with full unicode compatibility "out of the box", although it is certainly supported by the distribution.... I would be interested to hear your results if a fix like the package I suggested works for you, michaelpri

Comment: @sig_seg_v I did just try that command, but it did not work. I'm gonna do a bit more research

Comment: "longer than what a normal minus sign would be on the keyboard" is the strangest description.

Comment: off-topic, but how can you have a title bar in Chrome?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Must be a part of Ubuntu's version of Google Chrome

Comment: Interesting. The StackOverflow app on my iPhone and all occurrences of that character look like that. It's in Helvetica Neue (UltraLight for title bars).

Comment: @PSkocik _“Ubuntu isn't the problem. The window title font you're using is.”_ …which is “[Ubuntu](http://font.ubuntu.com/)”.

Comment: @michaelpri In your Java test, it seems you saved the file as UTF-8, but failed to tell the encoding to the compiler. With proper encoding, the character is still not accepted, but with a different error message. Also, similar to the C# example, the expression needs to be wrapped in some boilerplate code to even have a chance at being syntactically correct.

Comment: @ChristianSemrau For the C# code, I just put the line that has the actual code. The class and main method were there when I ran it, I just didn't want to bulk up the answer. For Java, I used [this](https://repl.it/languages/Java) and ran the expression in the terminal on the side. That is the error message it gave. I've edited the answer with what would happen if you ran `System.out.println(2+ 40);`.

Comment: I appreciate that you only provide the actual source line without the boilerplate. The error message is still misleading: The REPL uses ASCII encoding, thus disallowing any characters above ASCII code 127. When you replace the character with the equivalent Java escape sequence, you get `System.out.println(2+\u168040);`, which results in 3 error messages. The first is `Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u1680'`, the other two are the same as the last two in your answer.

Comment: I see [?] in iOS Safari, Chrome and the SO app

Comment: @ChristianSemrau My computer is getting compile errors when I try to do that (I'm using Eclipse). If you would like, you can edit the error post with the one that you get.

Comment: @michaelpri With proper encoding you get 3 compile errors. With IntelliJ and UTF-8, I get the first error `Error:(22, 30) java: illegal character: \5760` (the offending character is represented as octal). With the REPL you used, you got 5 compile errors, because the character is encoded as 3 bytes via UTF-8, and each of these bytes is an invalid ASCII character. I'd prefer you post the 3-error-version. :-)

Comment: @ChristianSemrau Would you mind editing it in? The REPL doesn't seem to work great and Eclipse is throwing a compile time error when I try to use the character or `\u1680`.

Comment: I inserted the output from my commandline Java compiler (from JDK 1.7.0_45).

Comment: perl5 fails with

   perl -e'2+ 40'
   Unrecognized character \xE1; marked by <-- HERE after 2+<-- HERE near column 3 at -e line 1.

but perl6 which embraces unicode a bit more has the same problem:

  $ ./perl6 -e'say 2+ 40'
  42

Comment: @PSkocik I finally fixed it :) Just needed to change the system title bar font.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Chrome, at least on Linux, has a setting to [use the system title bars](http://i.imgur.com/NgQLlC8.png) rather than its own.

Answer (score 43):

I guess it has to do something with the fact that for some strange reason it classifies as whitespace:

```
$ unicode  
U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
UTF-8: e1 9a 80  UTF-16BE: 1680  Decimal: &#5760;
  ( )
Uppercase: U+1680
Category: Zs (Separator, Space)
Bidi: WS (Whitespace)
```

Comment: If that is a copy and paste from your terminal, I'd like to know where you found the command `unicode`.

Comment: It's from the Ubuntu package named (wait for it...) `unicode` by Radovan Garabík.  The corresponding repo is at https://github.com/garabik/unicode .

Comment: OK, thanks for the github link. AFAICT, it isn't in the Fedora repos.

Comment: @PSkocik `' '.codePointAt(0)` at console will yield 5760. now google  5760 unicode.

Answer (score 6):

> I'd also like to know if there are more characters behaving like this.

I seem to remember reading a piece a while back about mischievously replacing semi-colons (U+003B) in someone's code with U+037E which is the Greek question mark.

They both look the same (to the extent that I believe the Greeks themselves use U+003B) but this article stated that the other one wouldn't work.

Some more information on this from Wikipedia is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#Greek_question_mark

And a (closed) question on using this as prank from SO itself. Not where I originally read it AFAIR though:
[JavaScript Prank / Joke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965331/javascript-prank-joke)

Answer (score 1):

Many languages won't compile this expression, but I was curious what Rust's compiler had to say on the topic. It is notoriously strict but will often give us knowledge and wisdom with loving kindness.

So I asked it to compile this:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", (2+ 40));
}
```

And the compiler replied:

```
error: unknown start of token: \u{1680}
  |
  |     println!("{}", (2+ 40));
  |                       ^
  |
help: Unicode character ' ' (Ogham Space mark) looks like ' ' (Space), but it is not
```

JavaScript, on the other hand, (tested with the latest and most commonly used browser today) seems to be pretty chill about that character and simply ignores it.