# NameError even with a direct, unconditional assignment on the line above

Tags: python, unicode

Just explain me how it is possible:

```
сhar = input()
print(char)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 2, in
>   
>       print(char) NameError: name 'char' is not defined

To make things more interesting, consider running that code in repl.it with double-checked python version:

```
import sys
print(f'Python version on this machine:\n{sys.version}')
сhar = input()
print(char)
```

> Python version on this machine: 
>   3.7.4 (default, Jul 13 2019, 14:20:24) 
>   [GCC 6.3.0 20170516] 
>   type anything 
>   Traceback (most recent call last): 
>     File "main.py", line 5, in  
>       print(char) 
>   NameError: name 'char' is not defined

Comment: How is this in any way behavior *of `input()`*? `input()` has nothing to do with how its returned value is bound to a name.

Comment: Are you sure your `char = input()` is not commented out and you are running the whole thing?

Comment: I can't replicate this, myself.

Comment: @Tomerikoo. I can reporduce this by, e.g., pasting the two lines into IPython as a unit.

Comment: I can replicate it, but only copying-and-pasting from the question. Name the destination variable to, say, `result` and it no longer happens.

Comment: now that's some active discussion

Comment: And this folks, is why it is important to create an example that people can copy and paste into a terminal.

Comment: Related: [Python the same char not equals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36137602/674039)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unicode identifier names.

```
>>> "char" == "сhar" 
False
```

One of those c is a vanilla 'LATIN SMALL LETTER C' but the other is `chr(0x441)`, i.e. ['CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0441/index.htm). On a typical machine they will render to the terminal with very similar looking (or exactly same) glyphs.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @StardustGogeta Are you typing it in, or are you copy-pasting?

Comment: I believe you have to copy paste it. @StardustGogeta

Comment: @iz_ Good catch, I never would have thought about that.

Comment: @wim How were you able to identify the issue so fast? Are you using a font that does not have identical glyphs, or had you seen this before?

Comment: I have seen similar underhanded tricks before.  In chrome browser, you can ctrl+f and type c you will notice one c from the question doesn't "highlight" on the page.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Try this: `list(ord(c) for c in 'сhar')`

Comment: @RolandSmith. I obviously did. My question was how wim immediately knew to do that. Of course it's the most plausible solution in hindsight...

Comment: @MadPhysicist As for me, I identified it by copying it to pycharm. It tells you `Identifier contains symbols from different languages: [LATIN, CYRILLIC] ...`

Answer (score 7):

Your `char = input()` contains the cyrillic character с (see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81))
Whereas the `print(char)` is purely latin.

This also reminds me of the [greek question mark prank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26965332/5709170), where the characters for semicolon and the question mark are rendered almost the same: `;;`

Edit: wim was faster

Comment: greek question mark is in my opinion much more brutal